# How to Call an existing Class with Parameters?

Tags: c#, multithreading, class, search, server

I´ve got a Class wich is called Clients on my multi threaded server.

My Question is how do i send data to an specified Client from another Class?
Here is my Listen Function from ServerMain Class.

```
    public static List<Client> clients;
    public static List<Thread> threads;
    private void Listen()
    {
        clients = new List<Client>();
        threads = new List<Thread>();

        int id = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            listenerSocket.Listen(0);
            Log.Status(" Waiting for a connection...");
            var commands = new ServerCommands();
            //commands.Wait();
            Client c1 = new Client(id, listenerSocket.Accept());
            clients.Add(c1);
            Log.Status("New Client Connected!");

            Thread t = new Thread(c1.Start);
            c1.SetThread = t;
            t.Start();
            id++;
        }
    }
```

And My Client Class with just one send Example

```
public class Client : IDisposable
{
    public int _id;
    public string _guid;
    public string Name;

        public Socket clientSocket;
    private Thread thread;

    public Client(int id, Socket socket)
    {
        this._id = id;
        this._guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        this.clientSocket = socket;
    }

    public Thread SetThread
    {
        set
        {
            this.thread = value;
        }
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this._id;
        }
    }

            public void Receive()
    {
        byte[] buffer;
        int readBytes;

        while (clientSocket != null && clientSocket.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                buffer = new byte[clientSocket.SendBufferSize];
                readBytes = clientSocket.Receive(buffer);

                if (readBytes > 0)
                {
                    Packet p = new Packet(buffer);

                    if (p.Type != PacketType.Disconnect)
                    {
                        new Task(() => Received(p)).Start();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CloseConnection();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                CloseConnection();
            }
        }
    }

    ////////// Example Send Fuction    ////////////
    private void Register(User user)
    {
        var res = Handler.RegisterDo(user);
        clientSocket.Send(res.ToBytes());
    }
}
```

I know i can send to all Connected Clients like this

```
        foreach(Client item in ServerMain.clients) //Client clients
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item._id);
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(item._guid);

        };
```

Am I missing something to identify?
The id Could do it (i think) but how do I call it then from outside?

Answer (score 0):

In my understand of your code, you just wrapper the `'client'` connection socket as the class client. you just need to call the  `'this.clientSocket'` field of the client class to `send()` or `receive()` data.

Comment: Yes this works when Iam in the Client Class, but what i wanted to know is how i could send data to the client with id 0 for example from another Class.
Or how i could change the selected client(Socket) by id in the class so i could call something like Client.SendDataTo(id, data)

Comment: Or any way to implement this kind of action